# Restrict to ping pc from remote PC

Tags: 16.04

How to restrict to ping my PC from any remote PC ? Is there any method for doing that.my PC is out of firewall , though I want to stop ping to my PC from outside. Can I do that ? if YES then how ? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: A firewall should help.

Answer (score 4):

Its possible with the following methods:

1. Setup kernel variable to drop all ping packets (temporary):

   ```
   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

   This instructs the kernel to simply ignore all ping 
   requests (ICMP type 0 messages)
   ```

   - To re-enable:

     ```
     echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
     ```
2. Add following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, append this line (permanent solution to step one):

   ```
   net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

   Reload with sysctl -p
   ```
3. Use iptables by setting the ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol):

   - Add these lines:

     ```
     iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

     OR

     iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
     ```
4. If using `firewalld`:

   - Check ICMP types available

     ```
     firewall-cmd --get-icmptypes
     ```
   - We are after `echo-reply`, so apply block

     ```
     firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-icmp-block=echo-reply
     ```

Sources:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-9-allow-icmp-ping.html

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-drop-block-all-ping-packets/

https://crybit.com/iptables-rules-for-icmp/

http://www.tecmint.com/firewalld-rules-for-centos-7/2/